# Is there any way to modify a file so that it generates a CRC error?

Tags: crc

Is there a programmatic (or not-programmatic) way to modify a file so that it generates a CRC error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a CD (a DVD is ok). Fill it with files. Take a screw. Scratch it in the central part radially 1-2 cm (half an inch) (I don't mean scratch the hole! Scratch the central part of the "data" area!!). Try to not scratch the inner part of the CD. One of the files should return CRC Error. You can use a black marker instead of a screw. Clearly you should scratch the bottom part of the CD (but interestingly, you can scratch the upper part of the CD and it will work too: the upper part is as necessary as the bottom part, because it reflects the light)

Comment: I think that could actually work. But is there a more delicate approach? (no CD's harmed :D)

Comment: @George You can do the same to a floppy disk! It's a little more tricky! Or you could damage a floppy disk with a magnet. You know that blank CD are very cheap right?

Comment: If I can't find another way I'll probably use the CD solution. 10x.

Comment: In fact, it would be more efficient to strongly scratch the label that the optical part, because the optical system is made to be as insensitive as possible to the state of the surface and the real data are just under the label. In addition, it would probably more efficient to scratch longitudinally because CD have a very strong error correction scheme and a radial scratch might be fully correctable.

Answer (score -1):

if you just add an extra character (say at the beginning) then that should be enough.

Comment: I am interested that the operating system returns the CRC error. I tried to binary modify files but that didn't help.